# Java - unreachable statement when i try to close database resources

Tags: java, sql, database

Whenever I try to close the resources rs.close() or stmt.close() or even conn.close() I get an error saying "unreachable statement". Strange thing is that it works in other methods. Maybe I forgot something?

```
   public static boolean exists(int av) {

    try {

        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DBURL, DBUSER, DBPASS);
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        String query = "SELECT id FROM audiovisuals WHERE id='" + av + "' LIMIT 1";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

        if(!rs.isBeforeFirst()) {
           return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }

        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        conn.close();

    } catch (SQLException e) {

        String error = "SQLException: " + e.getMessage() + "\nSQLState: " + e.getSQLState() + "\nVendorError: " + e.getErrorCode();
        return false;

    }

}
```

Comment: Where are you putting the close calls?

Comment: Probably you are putting them after `if(!rs.isBeforeFirst())`

Comment: You should you a try/finally construct :)

Comment: Please add at least one of the `close` statements to the code (at least in comments). Right now it's impossible to tell, what you're doing wrong.

Comment: @robermann why not try-with-resources?

Comment: I edited my code, no matter where i place the code, i keep getting the error :O i feel noob

Comment: @fabian +1 for JDK > 6

Comment: ill look at try-with-resources later thanks the tip, first i want to solve this error.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming here that you are getting unreachable statement because you are putting the calls after a return statement. You need to put the close calls in a finally block. So your method would look something like this:

```
 Connection conn = null;
 Statement stmt = null;
 ResultSet rs = null;
 try {

    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DBURL, DBUSER, DBPASS);
    stmt = conn.createStatement();
    String query = "SELECT id FROM audiovisuals WHERE id='" + av + "' LIMIT 1";
    rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

    if(!rs.isBeforeFirst()) {
       return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }

} catch (SQLException e) {

    String error = "SQLException: " + e.getMessage() + "\nSQLState: " + e.getSQLState() + "\nVendorError: " + e.getErrorCode();
    return false;

} finally {
    if (rs != null)
        rs.close();
    if (stmt != null)
        stmt.close();
    if (conn != null)
        conn.close();
}
```

Comment: unreported exception SQLException; must be caught or declared to be thrown, when finally starts.

Comment: @Dylan agreed, I was just trying to keep the code concise. You need to catch each one as well otherwise you end up leaking resources again.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a good place to use [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). With you code, it would look like this

```
public static boolean exists(int av) {

    try(Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DBURL, DBUSER, DBPASS);
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT id FROM audiovisuals WHERE id='" + av + "' LIMIT 1")){

        if(!rs.isBeforeFirst()) {
           return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {

        String error = "SQLException: " + e.getMessage() + "\nSQLState: " + e.getSQLState() + "\nVendorError: " + e.getErrorCode();
        return false;

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work! Is it possible to keep the database connection alive if i need to?

Comment: Not really. This closes the connection once it goes out of scope, which is what you should want; otherwise you'd have no way to access it again since the reference would be lost. If you want the connection to persist, then I'd suggest changing the program structure around to take the connection in as a parameter so you don't need to deal with it in the function.

Answer (score 1):

Your close statements can never be reached, since you return before in both if cases.

You can use *try-with-resources* to close `AutoCloseable`s automatically (everything you try to close is autocloseable):

```
try {

   String query = "SELECT id FROM audiovisuals WHERE id='" + av + "' LIMIT 1";
   try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DBURL, DBUSER, DBPASS);
         Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
         ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query)) {

        if(!rs.isBeforeFirst()) {
           return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }

    } // resources are automatically closed here
} catch (SQLException e) {
    String error = "SQLException: " + e.getMessage() + "\nSQLState: " + e.getSQLState() + "\nVendorError: " + e.getErrorCode();
}
return false;
```

Try-with-resources closes all resources (`conn`, `stmt` amd `rs`) even if an exception is thrown for one of the `close()` method calls.

Comment: Thats seems to work! Does it close everything? How can i keep the database connection alive in this case (if i need to)?

Comment: @Dylan: Not everything has to be a resource. You can of course initiate the connection outside of the `try-with-resources` and handle exceptions there with a conventional try-catch or move the connection resource to another `try-with-resources` surrounding the other (if you e.g. want make several queries in a loop). However since you declare connection as a local variable, it doesn't make sense to keep it alive in this method since you will loose access to the `Connection` object when the method is finished.